# What analysis is acceptable to assess reliability of a questionnarie composed for nominal and ordinal items?

Tags: ordinal-data, reliability

I need to asses the reliability of a questionnarie composed by a series of n items that respond to n characteristics. In each item the surveyed idividuals have to nominate three individuals and assign each one a value of a Likert scale that indicates the presence level of said characteristic.

Comment: The method for calculating reliability should reflect the method that is used to calculate the score. So how is the score calculated?